# Css javascript doesn't work inside Angularjs ng-view

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I am building a website using Angularjs, also I am using an admin theme for bootstrap.

The theme works fine, but when I divide it in views (ng-view), the different javascript based parts  stop working.

For example to open a modal window

> ```
>            <a href="javascript:;" class="primary-bg medium radius-all-2 display-block >btn basic-dialog">
>                <span class="button-content text-center float-none font-size-11 text->transform-upr">View Basic dialog example</span>
>            </a>
>
>        </div>
>        <div class="hide" id="basic-dialog" title="Basic dialog title">
>            <div class="pad10A">
>                Dialog content here
>            </div>
>        </div>
> ```

if I put this just in the index.html of the application it works fine, if I move it to an ng-view it doesn't work.

Comment: "*the different javascript based parts stop working.*" - Show us the javascript

Comment: I have a minified version of the js file which came with the theme I am using.

Comment: You can only have one `ng-view`

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain myself well enough. I am using this bootstrap theme http://agileui.com/fides-demo/index.html  If you take a look at some design elements like if you click on the user icon in the corner a drop down menu appears or the open and close left sidebar function, they work ok, but if I put the html inside a ng-view template they stop working.